# Allow access to page only from certain referrer

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, referrer

Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Hi there. I want to make a certain page on my website eg. site.com/content/B.html accessible only if you click the link that points to site.com/content/B.php from a specific page on the site eg. site.com/A.html

What I have tried to do so far is putting this code in a .htaccess file inside site.com/content:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.site.com/A.html$
    RewriteRule B.php - [F,NC]
```

This was supposed to return a 403 error only if you tried to open site.com/content/B.php using a link from some other site or just typing site.com/content/B.php into the address bar of the browser, but instead it returns a 403 error when opening it from site.com/A.html as well.

I expected for it to return a 403 error if opened from a different location, and for it to display B.php if opened from A.html

I hope that you follow and I would really appreciate some advice.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `[F]` flag doesn't return 404 it returns 403

Comment: Oh, my mistake! I'll update the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?site\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule (^|/)B\.php(/|$) - [F,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly. Is it possible to add a specific page to the referrer? If so what do I change?

Comment: Sure you can add something like `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} /somepage/ [NC]`